# 2D Game Framework in C++ and SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a simple 2D framework / engine for the first time based on two books and before the project gets too big I would like to know if I'm ordering things the right way. Maybe there are better ways of doing this. I tried to apply patterns so I could decouple as much as possible and keep things abstract.

For example this is the `Game` class:

```
#include "Game.h"

void Game::Create(int width, int height, const char * title, int window_flag, int renderer_flag){
      display.CreateWindow(800,600,"Game", SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}

void Game::Start(){
      Uint32 first_frame_ticks; float delta_time = 0;
      SDL_Renderer * renderer = display.GetRenderer();
      while(input_handler.GetLastEvent() != SDL_QUIT){
            first_frame_ticks = SDL_GetTicks();

            bool state_manager_empty = state_manager.isEmpty();
            //update
            input_handler.Update();
            if(!state_manager_empty) state_manager.GetGameState()->onUpdate(delta_time);

            //render
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            if(!state_manager_empty) state_manager.GetGameState()->onRender();
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            delta_time = (SDL_GetTicks() - first_frame_ticks) / 1000.0f;
      }

      display.Clear();
}

void Game::AddState(GameState* state){
      state->Set(display.GetRenderer(), &input_handler);
      state_manager.Add(state);
}
```

Or the Drawer class (wich I have some doubts about, the DrawEntity method is static)

```
#include "Drawer.h"

void Drawer::DrawEntity(Entity& entity, TextureManager* texture_manager, SDL_Renderer * renderer){
      texture_manager->Draw(entity.GetSprite(), entity.GetPosition(), renderer);
}
```

It acts like a mediator between TexureManager(wich draws texures) and Entity wich has all the information like position, scale, etc.

Finally the example input class

```
#include "InputHandler.h"
#include <cstdio>

InputHandler::InputHandler(){
      keyboard_state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
      printf("Event handler initialized\n");
}

void InputHandler::Update(){
      SDL_Event ev;
      while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev)){
            if(ev.type == SDL_KEYUP || ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                  keyboard_state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
            }else last_event = ev.type;
      }
}

bool InputHandler::isKeyPressed(SDL_Scancode key){
      if(keyboard_state[key]) return true;
      else return false;
}

Uint32 InputHandler::GetLastEvent(){
      return last_event;
}
```

I'm going to upload a dependency diagram as well as the GitHub repo:
[image]

## Github Repo with all the Code

https://github.com/grazianobolla/monke-engine

Comment: Long code isn't frowned upon on code review, you **should** post your full project here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update:

Well, if someone wants to know, I've done some changes for good,
one of the main problems I had was that I couldn't really "connect" the GameStates to the main Engine itself without passing a pointer to the engine (wich is messy) or individual pointers to the `InputHandler`, `Display`, etc.

The thing was that for example the InputHandler handled the Window events and the keyboard input, so for a GameState to have access to it, I would have to create a pointer to Game::InputHandler, so I did a few things:

First I created a `KeyboardHandle` class wich is totally independent from the Engine itself and its only function its to get keyboard input, that way I can make every game state to have an independent `KeyboardHandle`, also every game state has a pointer to the engine `Display` class, that means that from the game state you can get access to information like windows size or the `SDL_Renderer` without having much trouble, you add states from the `Engine` so the `Display` pointer is set at that moment.

The `GameState` class is the base for all games, now it looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "KeyboardHandle.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Display.h"

class GameState{
protected:
      KeyboardHandle keyboard;
      TextureManager texture_manager;
      Display * screen_display;
public:
      GameState(Display * display){ this->screen_display = display; }
      virtual void onStart() = 0;
      virtual void handleInput() = 0;
      virtual void onUpdate(float) = 0;
      virtual void onRender() = 0;
};
```

As you can see is almost all independent from the `Engine`, it just shares the display so we can render the graphics.

Here is an example state (drawing an image on the center of the screen):

```
#include "GameState.h"
#include "Entity.h"

class DefaultState : public GameState{
      Entity splash_logo;
public:
      DefaultState(Display * display) : GameState(display){ }

      void onStart(){
            texture_manager.Load("textures/splash_logo.png", "splash_logo", screen_display->GetRenderer());
            splash_logo = Entity("splash_logo", Vector2i(0, 0), Vector2i(336, 336), 1.0f);

            float center_x = (screen_display->GetWindowWidth() / 2) - splash_logo.GetCollisionBox().w / 2;
            float center_y = (screen_display->GetWindowHeight() / 2) - splash_logo.GetCollisionBox().h / 2;
            splash_logo.SetPosition({center_x, center_y});
      }

      void handleInput(){

      }

      void onUpdate(float delta_time){

      }

      void onRender(){
            texture_manager.Draw(splash_logo.GetSprite(), splash_logo.GetPosition(), screen_display->GetRenderer());
      }
};
```

And just for fun here is the dependency diagram:
[image: Dependency Diagram]